# How to include CSS files in Express.js views when not using a template engine?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, html-rendering

I'm trying to create an Express application. My limitations are that I cannot use any template engine for rendering HTML. There are (at least) two problems:

1. One of the problems that I foresee is how will I manage to manipulate the data based on what I need to show to the user. E.g. I have a transactions table in my database and I need to display an HTML table of all those transactions. The traditional way that I'm used is to utilize a template engine, where I can put a for loop that goes through the records.
2. I'm sending an HTML file when I call a specific route, but it cannot get the CSS files from another folder.

For problem 2. I've tried:

```
 app.get('/transactions', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/assets/html/transactions.html')))
```

and then in transactions.html I have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/shared/constants.css">
```

and other links to stylesheets.

When the page is displayed, it doesn't apply any of the styles. When I checked the source code in the browser, and I click the link for constants.css it shows the message:

```
Cannot GET /stylesheets/shared/constants.css
```

This doesn't seem like the right logic. What things should be changed?

Comment: you need to setup static routes: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example:

Assuming your folder structure:

```
app.js
|   +-- public
|   |   +-- stylesheets
|   |   |   +-- shared
|   |   |   |   +-- constants.css
...
```

You could simply server public folder as static like:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))

// In your html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/shared/constants.css">
```

With express, it's better to use `absolute` path over `relative` path.

Or set up virtual path for your static files like:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + "/public"))

// In your html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/shared/constants.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Example worked for me:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/publlic"))
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
res.render('index');
})

// In your html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/shared/constants.css">
```

With this method, I use engine like you.